# how to import the same file with different var's

Tags: python

Yo! first of all sorry for any Miss-spellings... my English is not my prime language...

**explanation of the program -**

so im just started to code and as a beginner wanted to create a very simple program with a simple login, personal info and a calculator.
so the flow is as so
Login() > var_list() > main_menu() (from here you can edit the var list, open calculator, logout.. whatever...)

**explanation of the problem -**

so as i said this is a simple program, you login, you'll be promoted to enter your profile info, then the info will be display on the main menu 
in the main menu one of the options is to change your profile by relaunch the var_list function.
the var list function will just create a 3 variuables that contain your name, age and address in a file called profile.py (see code) 
then the menu import's "profile.py" to display the content in the main menu
but when I run the Var_list function again from the main menu it will not refresh any on the var's that had printed... it did changed in the "profile.py" file tho but wont display the changes only the

**var_list function:**

```
def var_list():  # register to the program || cant get it to refresh after program has started... hlp plz
    on = 1
    while on == 1:
        print("This is just to fill out your profile")
        try:
            name = input("Your Name:\t")
            age = int(input("Your Age:\t"))
            address = input("Your address:\t")
            on = 0
            #________file_write__________
            f = open("profile.py", "w")
            f.write("name = ")
            f.write("\"")
            f.write(name)
            f.write("\"")
            f.write("\nage = ")
            f.write("\"")
            f.write(str(age))
            f.write("\"")
            f.write("\naddress = ")
            f.write("\"")
            f.write(address)
            f.write("\"")
            f.close()

        except ValueError:
            print("invalid syntax")
```

**display menu function:**

```
def display_menu():  # Display menu
    on=1
    while on==1:
        from profile import name, age, address
        print("\nHello", name, age, "from", address,
              "\t\t• %s seconds •" % (int(time.time()) - int(start_time)),"\n")
        print("1 • Logout")
        print("2 • Refresh Time")
        print("3 • Edit Profile") (this is the var_list function)
        print("4 • simple calc")
        print("5 • Exit")
        on=0
```

hope i gave enough info for debugging this...
any help will be much appreciated!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, re-importing a module doesn't actually recompile it. You can however partially fix that using `importlib`:

```
import profile 
... # in the meantime, profile.py is modified
from importlib import reload
reload(profile)
```

so that you can use qualified variable names (`profile.name`, `profile.age`, `profile.address`). I'm not sure if there is a way to make that work with the `from profile import ...` syntax in your example, but it seems like a minor inconvenience.